# Is it permissible to accept Tips from Mushrik(s)?

Tags: work, christianity, other-religions

> عَنْ حَكِيمَ بْنَ حِزَامٍ قَالَ: كَانَ مُحَمَّدٌ  صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم أَحَبَّ رَجُلٍ فِي النَّاسِ إِلَيَّ فِي الْجَاهِلِيَّةِ فَلَمَّا تَنَبَّأَ وَخَرَجَ إِلَى الْمَدِينَةِ شَهِدَ حَكِيمُ بْنُ حِزَامٍ الْمَوْسِمَ وَهُوَ كَافِرٌ فَوَجَدَ حُلَّةً لِذِي يَزَنَ تُبَاعُ فَاشْتَرَاهَا بِخَمْسِينَ دِينَارًا لِيُهْدِيَهَا لِرَسُولِ اللهِ  ‌صلی ‌اللہ ‌علیہ ‌وآلہ ‌وسلم ‌فَقَدِمَ بِهَا عَلَيْهِ الْمَدِينَةَ فَأَرَادَهُ عَلَى قَبْضِهَا هَدِيَّةً فَأَبَى قَالَ عُبَيْدُ اللهِ حَسِبْتُ أَنَّهُ قَالَ إِنَّا لَا نَقْبَلُ شَيْئًا مِنْ الْمُشْرِكِينَ وَلَكِنْ إِنْ شِئْتَ أَخَذْنَاهَا بِالثَّمَنِ فَأَعْطَيْتُهُ حِينَ أَبَى عَلَيَّ الْهَدِيَّةَ .
>
> حکیم بن حزام سے مروی ہے کہتے ہیں کہ دور جاہلیت میں محمد صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم مجھے بہت زیادہ محبوب تھے۔ جب  آپ صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم کونبوت ملی اور آپ مدینے کی طرف (ہجرت کر) آئے تو حکیم بن حزام تجارت کے موسم میں بازار آئے ابھی وہ کافر تھے۔ انہوں نے ذی یزن کا ایک جبہ  دیکھا جو فروخت کے لئے پیش کیا گیا تھا، اسے پچاس دینار کے بدلے خرید لیا تاکہ رسول اللہ صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم کو تحفہ دے سکیں۔ اس جبے کو لے کر مدینے آگئے اور آپ کو بطور تحفہ دینا چاہا تو آپ نے انکار کر دیا۔ عبیداللہ کہتے ہیں کہ: میرا خیال ہے کہ آپ صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم نے فرمایا: ہم مشرکین سے کوئی چیز قبول نہیں کرتے لیکن اگر تم چاہو تو ہم قیمت کے بدلے اسے لے سکتے ہیں۔ جب انہوں نے تحفہ لینے سے انکار کیا تو میں نے انہیں (قیمتاً) دے دیا۔
>
> ( )
> Al-Silsila-tus-Sahiha#1822
> Status: صحیح

According to above Hadith, the Holy Prophet (PBUH) refused to accept a gift from Mushrik, but asked him to sell it to be accepted.

Is a tip and Gift equal? Especially when it comes from Mushrik?

I'm a freelancer. I work over a platform. Sometimes with rewards, I am given some extra tip. Usually clients are Christians. I am not sure sure if accepting would be same as accepting gift from Mushrik.

Comment: Scholars hold different views on the topic the worst one could say is that it is makruh. But there are evidences for both permission and prohibition. Please be aware that reading and understanding a hadith doesn't make you a scholar who could conclude rulings from it. I've read the story of a convert who toke ibn Hajar's fath al-Bary and studied it and noted his own conclusion as fiqh rulings. Later he studied the book with a hadith scholar Sho'ayb al-Arnaout -if i remember well- and realized how wrong he was with his conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the scholars consider it permitted to accept a gift from a mushrik. Among their evidence are the ahadith:

> أهدى ملك أيلة للنبي صلى الله عليه وسلم بغلة بيضاء، وكساه بردا
>
> The king of 'Aila presented a white mule and a cloak as a gift to the Prophet ﷺ.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/58/4)</sup>

> إن أكيدر دومة أهدى إلى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم
>
> The present was sent to the Prophet (ﷺ) by Ukaidir (Christian king) from Dauma
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/51/48)</sup>

> ثم جاء رجل مشرك، مشعان طويل، بغنم يسوقها، فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم:  بيعا أم عطية، أو قال: أم هبة؟
>
> A very tall pagan came driving sheep. The Prophet (ﷺ) asked him, "Will you sell us (a sheep) or give it as a present?"
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/51/50)</sup>

> أن المقوقس، أهدى إلى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم هدية فقبلها
>
> Muqawqis (the ruler of Alexandria) sent gifts to the Prophet ﷺ and he accepted
>
> <sup>— [Musannaf ibn Abi Shaybah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/37953#p1)</sup>

> أن يهودية أتت النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم بشاة مسمومة، فأكل منها
>
> A Jewess brought a poisoned sheep for the Prophet (ﷺ) who ate from it.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/51/49)</sup>

> أعطها هاجر
>
> [ The tyrant gifted Hagar as a servant to Sarah, the wife of Abraham عليه السلام]
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/203)</sup>

There are also reports that the prophet refused gifts from disbelievers at certain occasions. These include the gift of ['Iyad ibn Himar](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/21/38) and the one which you have quoted etc.

The scholars holding the opinion of permissibility have suggested various explanations for these:

- They were abrogated
- They apply to the idolators not to the Ahl al-Kitab (Jews, Christians)
- The prophet accepted or refused when there was an interest served by it, such as persuading the person towards Islam.